# Can we find a better wording for "Looks OK" in the review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, user-interface

When I do reviewing in the queues, especially the low quality queue, the option to not nuke the post but let it live as it is, is called "Looks OK".

I cringe every time I have to click this. Just because the post does not meet the criteria to be nuked from orbit in the review queue, does **not** mean it looks okay. Most are *horrible*, they need to be *downvoted* and/or commented on. And I do. And then I have to click "Looks OK" on posts that certainly do not, to complete the review process.

The only time I really *mean* it when I click that button is when I am 100% sure it's a positive audit anyway.

So, I know it's a minor detail, but can we maybe find a better wording for that button?

Comment: Maybe "No moderation required" would get the message across, but that string's probably a bit too long for the button. It's hard to be 100% precise *and* concise

Comment: I propose the wording "Let it go" ... bonus points if it also plays the song on clicking ....

Comment: *"Don't nuke (yet)"* ... may not be the right wording   but sure how you feel about them a lot of the time and sure is a lot less affirmation of quality

Comment: Any reason why the wording from Late Answers / First Posts can't be used?

Comment: Alternative suggestion: Split "Looks OK" to "Looks OK" and "Downvote"

Comment: believe it or not but initially this button label was ["Looks Good"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/165773)

Comment: i vote to rename the hole lot, they all are misleading and bad wording and often don't help to decide

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the [design for the revamp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346902/improving-review-queues-design-overview-i-onboarding-and-updating-workflows) has "Looks OK" as "Approve" (which is not necessarily better). Granted, the 6-8 weeks for that are, as of the time of writing, [expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353982/we-expect-some-q3-projects-to-be-delayed) to take longer than anticipated.

Answer (score 4):

what about "Acceptable" or my favorite since chernobyl "not great not terrible"